# Is it possible to run Windows as a Xen VM without VT, using Qemu-dm?

Tags: xen, kvm-virtualization, qemu, paravirtualization

Is it possible to run windows as a virtual machine under Xen using `qemu-dm`? If so, how can it be done?

Since Xen without **VT** technology supports only para-virtualization, can `qemu-dm`, the emulator that helps VMs to access network and disk, can be configured to emulate whole hardware?

In case of KVM, can `qemu-dm` do this for systems with no hardware-assisted virtualization support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows will only run in HVM and PV-HVM modes (which use the modified version of QEmu and require VT/AMD-V)

You're looking for PV mode if you require a non-VT/AND-V CPU, and it only works with modified Operating Systems:

> Xen PV guest kernels exist for Linux, NetBSD, FreeBSD, OpenSolaris and Novell Netware operating systems.

From: [Xen Overview](http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/XenOverview)

QEmu can run Windows on just about any hardware, though performance may be "lacking" without the advanced hardware capabilities that enable KVM.